# Why they use Bitwise XOR operator in the XOR-Shift algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, operators

Why the Bitwise XOR operator is used in the XOR-Shift algorithm (Uses to generate random numbers) instead of others Bitwise operations like OR, AND.. etc?

Comment: Because otherwise the name XOR-Shift would be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR is the only bitwise operator, that can toggle bits from 0 to 1, or 1 to 0. This is essential in any feedback operator, that is supposed to generate a non-monotonic function and specifically to generate a periodic function, so that f(n+N) = f(n), for some N.

E.g. adding bits would generate non-periodic simple sequences:

0, 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, ... until all bits are filled   or
   0, 10, 1010, 101010, 10101010, ...

Anding bits would have the opposite effect, where the starting value should be all bits set:

1111111...1,  ..., 1111, 111, 11, 1, 0

In mathematical sense the first sequences are purely growing and the last sequence is diminishing, none of which produce even a seemingly random sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I could understand why they use XOR operator to generate random number in the XOR-Shift algorithm.

Comment: Could or could not? Xor is fast and easily portable to any word lenght contrary to division (modulus) or multiplication.

Comment: sorry, "Could not".
Do you mean, XOR is faster than AND, OR ?

Comment: read the answer again: or doesn't produce zero bits from nonzero input. Xor does and so does mul/div. But as bitwise operator its the fastest suitable operator.